# How can I resolve INDEX MATCH errors caused by discrepancies in the spelling of names across multiple data sources?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I've set up a Google Sheets workbook that synthesizes data from a few different sources via manual input, `IMPORTHTML` and `IMPORTRANGE`. Once the data is populated, I'm using `INDEX MATCH` to filter and compare the information and to `RANK` each data set.

Since I have multiple data inputs, I'm running into a persistent issue of names not being written exactly the same between sources, even though they're the same person. First names are the primary culprit (i.e. Mary Lou vs Marylou vs Mary-Lou vs Mary Louise) but some last names with special symbols (umlauts, accents, tildes) are also causing errors. When Sheets can't recognize a match, the `INDEX MATCH` and `RANK` functions both break down.

I'm wondering how to better unify the data automatically so my Sheet understands that each occurrence is actually the same person (or "value").

Since you can't edit the results of an `IMPORTHTML` directly, I've set up "helper columns" and used functions like `TRIM` and `SPLIT` to try and fix instances as I go, but it seems like there must be a simpler path.

It feels like `IFS` could work but I can't figure how to integrate it. Also thinking this may require a script, which I'm just beginning to study.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve and the corresponding errors: [Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bQ-zPDutgn_Xwq9LGZPWog9-WGX9D89c_bDy34DJ4HM/edit?usp=sharing)

The first tab is attempting to pull and `RANK` data from tabs 2 and 3. Sample formulas from the Summary tab, row 3 (Amelia Rose):

`Cell B3: =INDEX('Q1 Sales'!B:B, MATCH(A3,'Q1 Sales'!A:A,0))`

`Cell C3: =RANK(B3,$B$2:B,1)`

`Cell D3: =INDEX('Q2 Sales'!B:B, MATCH(A3,'Q2 Sales'!A:A,0))`

`Cell E3: =RANK(D3,$D$2:D,1)`

I'd be grateful for any insight on how to best index `'Q2Sales'!B3` as the correct value for `'Summary'!D3.` Thanks in advance - the thoughtful answers on Stack Overflow have gotten me this far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to counter every possible scenario do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "-|\s", )), 
 {REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(REGEXREPLACE('Q2 Sales'!A2:A, "-|\s", )), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "-|\s", )))), 'Q2 Sales'!B2:B}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Brilliant! Can't thank you enough for the quick reply. 

One follow up Q: how would you append this solution to account for nicknames (i.e. Ben vs Benjamin, Will vs William)? I dropped your code into the sample spreadsheet as indicated and changed ```A5``` and ```A17``` on the ```'Q2 Sales'``` tab to the truncated names as an example. 

Thanks again for your insight!

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "-|\s", )), 
 {REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(REGEXREPLACE('Q2 Sales'!A2:A, "-|\s", )), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "-|\s", )))), 'Q2 Sales'!B2:B}, 2, 0),
 VLOOKUP(LOWER(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "..."))), 
 {REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT('Q2 Sales'!A2:A, "..."))), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, LOWER(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "..."))))), 'Q2 Sales'!B2:B}, 2, 0))))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/w86PK.png

Comment: Amazing - thank you! Gonna take me a minute to unpack how you did this, but it works flawlessly. Much obliged.